# Deep Linking from external source into MC HubExchange app

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is it possible to build a link to be placed on a website or in an email which will allow direct access into a HubExchange app in the Marketing Cloud (https://mc.exacttarget.com/cloud/) application?

Example: Provide a link in an email to view a report inside a hub exchange app the user has added to their account via the marketplace.

I would imagine the link would redirect the the MC login screen and then redirect on login to the link within the app iframe.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible - what have you tried so far? The links in the app switcher open the application, but not within the MC window.

Comment: I also don't believe this is possible yet.

Comment: This would be really useful. I hope such support is added soon.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I am finding - no this is not currently possible.  If you would like, feel free to add this as a suggestion in 3sixty.

Answer (score 0):

Good news! This is coming, in fact it's already on the sandbox server, so I assume it's only a matter of time before this rolls into production. URLs are now based on the MC feature or app you are using, for example: https://mc.test.exacttarget.com/cloud/#app/yourappname